# ERROR: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, migration

actualmente estoy usando net 6.0 y EF 6.0.8 al intentar hacer una migración me sale este error.

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Pedido_CadetePedido_Id_pedido". The conflict occurred in database "Cadeteria", table "dbo.CadetePedido",
column 'Id_cadPed'.
The statement has been terminated.

¿Alguien me podria ayudar?

este son los codigos: DataContext.cs

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Cadetes> Cadetes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Clientes> Clientes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Pedido> Pedido { get; set; }
public DbSet<CadetesPedido> cadetesPedidos { get; set; }
// public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    List<Cadetes> listCadete = new List<Cadetes>();
    listCadete.Add(new Cadetes() { Id_cadete = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc0"), Nombre = "Jaun Castellanos", Direccion = "Entre rios", Telefono = "231321231" });
    listCadete.Add(new Cadetes() { Id_cadete = Guid.Parse("0a9fa564-0604-4dfa-88df-3636fe395651"), Nombre = "Ana Hume", Direccion = "independencia", Telefono = "231321231" });
    listCadete.Add(new Cadetes() { Id_cadete = Guid.Parse("0a9fa564-0604-4dfa-88df-3636fe395678"), Nombre = "Fer Hume", Direccion = "independencia", Telefono = "654321" });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Cadetes>(Cadete =>
    {
        Cadete.ToTable("Cadete");
        Cadete.HasKey(p => p.Id_cadete);
        //Cadete.HasMany(cp => cp.Cadp).WithOne(c => c.Cadete).HasForeignKey(c => c.Id_cadPed);

        Cadete.Property(p => p.Nombre).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        Cadete.Property(p => p.Direccion).IsRequired();
        Cadete.Property(p => p.Telefono).IsRequired();
        Cadete.Ignore(x => x.Pedido);
        Cadete.Ignore(x => x.Cadp);
        Cadete.HasData(listCadete);
    });

    List<Clientes> listaCliente = new List<Clientes>();
    listaCliente.Add(new Clientes() { Id_cliente = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc3"), Nombre = "Pancho Castellanos", Direccion = "Entre rios", Telefono = "5231234" });
    listaCliente.Add(new Clientes() { Id_cliente = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc1"), Nombre = "Lucio Hume", Direccion = "independencia", Telefono = "8321156" });
    listaCliente.Add(new Clientes() { Id_cliente = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc5"), Nombre = "Val Hume", Direccion = "independencia", Telefono = "975313" });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Clientes>(Clientes =>
    {
        Clientes.ToTable("Cliente");
        Clientes.HasKey(p => p.Id_cliente);

        Clientes.Property(p => p.Id_cliente).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        Clientes.Ignore(p => p.Id_pedido);
        Clientes.Property(p => p.Nombre).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        Clientes.Property(p => p.Direccion).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        Clientes.Property(p => p.Telefono).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        Clientes.Property(p => p.Referencia);

        Clientes.HasData(listaCliente);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Pedido>(Pedido =>
    {
        List<Pedido> Listped = new List<Pedido>();
        Listped.Add(new Pedido() { Id_pedido = Guid.Parse("adc4aba6-b2b6-4ca6-a715-e563987fd02e"), Id_cliente = Guid.Parse("7b5e9399-8e95-4ae8-8745-9542a01e2cc3"), Obs = "Coca", Estado = "Pendiente" });

        Pedido.ToTable("Pedido");
        Pedido.HasKey(p => p.Id_pedido);
        Pedido.HasOne(c => c.Cliente).WithMany(p => p.listaPedido).HasForeignKey(c => c.Id_cliente);
        //Pedido.HasOne(cp => cp.Cadp).WithOne(p => p.Pedido).HasForeignKey<CadetesPedido>(cp => cp.Id_pedido);

        Pedido.Property(p => p.Id_pedido).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        Pedido.Property(p => p.Obs).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        Pedido.Property(p => p.Estado).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(12);
        Pedido.Ignore(x => x.Id_cadPed);
        Pedido.Ignore(x => x.Cadete);
        Pedido.Ignore(p => p.Cadp);

        Pedido.HasData(Listped);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CadetesPedido>(CP =>
    {

        CP.ToTable("CadetePedido");
        CP.HasKey(Cp => Cp.Id_cadPed);
        CP.Property(CP => CP.Id_cadPed).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        CP.HasOne(c => c.Cadete).WithMany(cp => cp.Cadp).HasForeignKey(c => c.Id_cadete);
        CP.HasOne(p => p.Pedido).WithOne(cp => cp.Cadp).HasForeignKey<Pedido>(p => p.Id_cadPed);

    });
}
}
```

Cadete.cs

```
public class Cadetes
{
public Guid Id_cadete;
public string Nombre { get; set; }
public string Direccion { get; set; }
public string Telefono { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual ICollection<Pedido>? Pedido { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual List<CadetesPedido>? Cadp { get; set; }

}
```

Pedido.cs

```
public partial class Pedido
{
public Guid Id_pedido { get; set; }
public virtual Guid Id_cliente { get; set; }

public string Obs { get; set; }
public string Estado { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Guid? Id_cadPed { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Clientes? Cliente { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Cadetes? Cadete { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual CadetesPedido? Cadp { get; set; }
```

}

CadetePedido.cs

```
public class CadetesPedido
{


public Guid Id_cadPed { get; set; }
public virtual Guid Id_pedido { get; set; }
public virtual Guid Id_cadete { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Cadetes? Cadete { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Pedido? Pedido { get; set; }


}
```

Antes de crear la ultima clase, todo me andaba perfectamente. Mi idea era crear una tabla intermedia para Cadete y Pedido.